# Getting error while running buildout for Setting Plumi and Zope Server on Linux using command "python3 bootstrap.py -c production.cfg"

Tags: plone, buildout, zope3

I was installing Plumi for creating a production site. after installing plumi.app i faced below error whie running buildout using command : python3 bootstrap.py -c production.cfg
Note:: Zope is installed and zope user is added..
The ERROR IS BELOW::[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ThRL.png)

```
root@Saif:/home/plumi.app# /bin/python3 bootstrap.py && ./bin/buildout -v
ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-33.1.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmpvwkpnumd
Now working in /tmp/tmpvwkpnumd/setuptools-33.1.1
Building a Setuptools egg in /tmp/tmpgfkbh3om
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'setuptools/_vendor'
/tmp/tmpgfkbh3om/setuptools-33.1.1-py3.8.egg
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.buildout' (maybe misspelled?)
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.buildout' (maybe misspelled?)
No local packages or working download links found for zc.buildout
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('zc.buildout')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 171, in <module>
    raise Exception(
Exception: Failed to execute command:
'/bin/python3', '-c', 'from setuptools.command.easy_install import main; main()', '-mZqNxd', '/tmp/tmpgfkbh3om', 'zc.buildout'
root@Saif:/home/plumi.app# ^C
root@Saif:/home/plumi.app# python3 bootstrap.py -c production.cfg
ez_setup.py is deprecated and when using it setuptools will be pinned to 33.1.1 since it's the last version that supports setuptools self upgrade/installation, check https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/581 for more info; use pip to install setuptools
Downloading https://pypi.io/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-33.1.1.zip
Extracting in /tmp/tmp6dqehae9
Now working in /tmp/tmp6dqehae9/setuptools-33.1.1
Building a Setuptools egg in /tmp/tmpdja0839z
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'setuptools/_vendor'
/tmp/tmpdja0839z/setuptools-33.1.1-py3.8.egg
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.buildout' (maybe misspelled?)
Couldn't find index page for 'zc.buildout' (maybe misspelled?)
No local packages or working download links found for zc.buildout
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('zc.buildout')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bootstrap.py", line 171, in <module>
    raise Exception(
Exception: Failed to execute command:
'/usr/bin/python3', '-c', 'from setuptools.command.easy_install import main; main()', '-mZqNxd', '/tmp/tmpdja0839z', 'zc.buildout'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'setuptools/_vendor'
```

I found out that setuptools version 33.1.1 doesn't have `vendor` folder.

https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/tree/v33.1.1/setuptools